# How can I send someone the most recent version of one branch of my git repo without version control history?

Tags: git, git-bundle

I'm trying to send someone a copy of the current state of one branch on my Git repository. He doesn't have access to the repository itself and doesn't need version control history. I would also like to send the file over email, so including excessive history will cause the file size to be too large.

I could manually clone that branch myself with --depth=1 in a new folder, then compress that folder and send it, but that seems like a roundabout way to accomplish what could be done with git-bundle. However, if I do `git bundle create repo.bundle -1 HEAD`, which according to https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle should bundle only the 1 most recent commit, I get a 590 B file and an error when I try to clone from the bundle to test it:

```
error: Repository lacks these prerequisite commits:
error: 123456...             # example SHA, HEAD~1
fatal: bad object 789101...  # example SHA, HEAD
fatal: remote did not send all necessary objects
```

How can I get only the most recent version of the branch from my local repository?

Comment: Perhaps, there's a smarter way to do this, but just removing `.git` folder should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If your friend doesn't need the `.git` directory on his machine, then you don't need to zip it. You just need to archive your project from the tip of the branch you are.

```sh
cd my-project

git checkout my-feature-to-share

zip -r my-project.zip .
```

This will produce an archive that you can freely share to your friend. If you wish to NOT share the `.git` folder, you can exclude it with the `-x` option.